# Updating self joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I cloned  several categories that has shop_id = 233 to shop_id=255 in my MySQL table.The structure of the table is:

```
Table name: **t_category**

fields: id, name, parent_id, shop_id
```

Now I have these cloned categories with shop_id = 255, but parent_id's are related to categories in shop_id=233. I should update parent_id's of the cloned categories.

First I am trying to write a self join like:

```
SELECT p.id AS 'Parent',
   c.id AS 'Child' 
FROM t_category c
INNER JOIN t_category p ON p.id = c.`parent_id` and c.shop_id = 255
```

How can I update the cloned category's parent ids?

Comment: How can you distinguish between cloned and original rows?

Comment: Do you have some way of relating parent_id's in categories in 233 to their respective categories in 255?

Comment: @TabAlleman names are exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if I understand, you want to take each ID in shop 255, find its corresponding id in shop 233, get the parent of that id (in 233), then find the corresponding parent in shop 255, right?

Assuming there are no duplicate names in each shop, this is how I would do it in SQL Server.. probably the same for MySQL:

```
UPDATE t255
SET parent_id=p255.id
FROM t_category t255
INNER JOIN t_category t233 ON t255.Name=t233.Name AND t233.shop_id=233
INNER JOIN t_category p233 ON p233.id=t233.parent_id
INNER JOIN t_category p255 ON p255.Name=p233.Name
WHERE t255.shop_id=255
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're trying to do is set the shop_id on the parent records, so something like this should do it:

```
UPDATE t_category
    SET shop_id = 233
WHERE id IN (SELECT p.id from t_category c JOIN t_category p ON p.id = c.`parent_id` and c.shop_id = 255)
```